# why object's field passed as props does not cause re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

Isn't it true, that react components are re-rendered whenever their props are changed?
In the following code, the component Button is not re-renders altough that the props val is changed.

The code is executed in https://react.dev/learn/installation#try-react

```
import { useState, useEffect , memo, useRef} from 'react';

function createTimer() {
    return{
        secondsPassed: 0,
        increase() {
            this.secondsPassed += 1
        },
        reset() {
            this.secondsPassed = 0
        }
    }
}
const Button=function Button({val}){

  const ref = useRef(0);

  ref.current = ref.current + 1;
  
  return <button >Seconds passed:
   {val} re-renders:{ref.current-1}</button>};

  


function Greeting({ name }) {
   const [timer, setValue] = useState(createTimer());

   useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      timer.increase(); 
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  });
  
  return <Button val={timer.secondsPassed}/>

}


export default function App() {
  
  return <Greeting name="world" />
}
```

Comment: Your `timer` state object never changes.

Comment: First, you didn't replace the object `timer` refers to. Changing an object's fields isn't considered a change. Second, you have to change it via `setValue` in order for the state change to be recognized by React

Comment: What do you expect to happen?